# How can define type of {state,...params}

Tags: javascript, typescript, typeerror

```js
const state:objectType ={
    a :'a',
    b : 'b'
}

type objectType = {[key : string] : string}

type objectType3 = {c: number,d : number}

const params:objectType3= {
    c:1,
    d:2
}

const low = {state,...params};
interface newONe {
    state : objectType | objectType3;
}

function g(
    {state,...params} : newONe){
    console.log(state);
    console.log(params.c)
}

g({state,...params});
```

In this i want to access params.c but getting error like c does not exists on params.

Can any body help me out how can i can type case `{state,...params}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this if you want to destructure the params

```js
type newONe = { state: objectType } & objectType3

function g({ state, ...params }: newONe) {
  console.log(state)
  console.log(params.c)
}

g({ state, ...params })
```

Or this way if you do not want to destructure them

```js
type newONe = { state: objectType, params: objectType3 }

function g({ state, params }: newONe) {
  console.log(state)
  console.log(params.c)
}

g({ state, params })
```